# Regular Expressions to Update a Text File in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, text

I'm trying to write a script to update a text file by replacing instances of certain characters, (i.e. 'a', 'w') with a word (i.e. 'airplane', 'worm').

If a single line of the text was something like this:

```
a.function(); a.CallMethod(w); E.aa(w);
```

I'd want it to become this:

```
airplane.function(); airplane.CallMethod(worm); E.aa(worm);
```

The difference is subtle but important, I'm only changing 'a' and 'w' where it's used as a variable, not just another character in some other word. And there's many lines like this in the file. Here's what I've done so far:

```
original = open('original.js', 'r')
modified = open('modified.js', 'w')
# iterate through each line of the file
for line in original:
    # Search for the character 'a' when not part of a word of some sort
    line = re.sub(r'\W(a)\W', 'airplane', line)
    modified.write(line)

original.close()
modified.close()
```

I think my RE pattern is wrong, and I think i'm using the re.sub() method incorrectly as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should enclose the result you're getting so we could see what is it that you're not happy with.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about the semantic meaning of the text you're changing with a regular expression, then you'd likely be better served by parsing it instead. Luckily python has two good modules to help you with parsing Python. Look at the [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#module-ast) and the [Parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html#module-parser) modules. There's probably others for JavaScript if that's what you're doing; like [slimit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit).

Future reference on Regular Expression questions, there's a lot of helpful information here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info
- [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

And it took me 30 minutes from never having used this JavaScript parser in Python (replete with installation issues: please note the right ply version) to writing a basic solution given your example. You can too.

```
# Note: sudo pip3 install ply==3.4 && sudo pip3 install slimit

from slimit import ast
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor

data = 'a.funktion(); a.CallMethod(w); E.aa(w);'

tree = Parser().parse(data)
for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree):
if isinstance(node, ast.Identifier):
    if node.value == 'a':
        node.value = 'airplaine'
    elif node.value == 'w':
        node.value = 'worm'

print(tree.to_ecma())
```

It runs to give this output:

```
$ python3 src/python_renames_js_test.py
airplaine.funktion();
airplaine.CallMethod(worm);
E.aa(worm);
```

Caveats:

1. `function` is a reserved word, I used `funktion`
2. the `to_ecma` method pretty prints; there is likely another way to output it closer to the original input.

Comment: I don't think I need a parser because I'm pretty sure if I can successfully match 'a' surrounded by anything except for another letter, i'll be fine. I'm just struggling with the correct RE pattern.

Comment: @Asif Okay then, you've got this; no problem. Sorry I tried to help. How do you know if the line isn't actually inside quotes that start and end on other lines?

Answer (score 1):

```
line = re.sub(r'\ba\b', 'airplane', line)
```

should get you closer. However, note that you will also be replacing `a.CallMethod("That is a house")` into `airplane("That is airplane house")`, and `open("file.txt", "a")` into `open("file.txt", "airplane")`. Getting it right in a complex syntax environment using RegExp is hard-to-impossible.

Comment: Does hard-to-impossible mean impossible?

Comment: Depends on your text, and on your RegExp dialect. E.g. Ruby can write whole parsers in RegExp; Python's is quite a bit less powerful. But either way it is very easy to get airplane case that you just didn't expect.